# Why openshift creates two secrets when I create a serviceaccount

Tags: openshift-3, k8s-serviceaccount

I have created a serviceaccount with `edit` permission on openshift:

```
oc create serviceaccount gitlab-ci
oc policy add-role-to-user edit system:serviceaccount:test-project:gitlab-ci
```

but when I check the secrets, I see two secrets regarding the serviceaccount, both have the same structure but with a different values:

[image]

What are the uses of two secrets and why can't we handle it via one secret?

Answer (score 0):

The anser is in the documentation: [Understanding and creating service accounts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.8/authentication/understanding-and-creating-service-accounts.html):

> Each service account automatically contains two secrets:
>
> - An API token
> - Credentials for the OpenShift Container Registry

Comment: The `Credentials for the OpenShift Container Registry` is different and it has a name like `gitlab-ci-dockercfg-aaa` which is different from `gitlab-ci-token-XXX`

Comment: The credential for the container registry is not a service account token. OpenShift clearly shows in the output by the OP that these both are service-account-tokens which their documentation also does not clarify.

Comment: This is happening also in Openshift 4.11. @Yashar did your service account already have two API token BEFORE you granted him edit permissions?